# Java List<Float[]> from JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a data structure like this `List<Float[]>` that holds two floats from a custom JPA Query.

Something like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a.count1, a.count2 FROM Counter a, .......)
List<Float[]> functionc1c2();
```

How can I access and store the two terms in `List<Float[]>` into some float variables?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access and store the two terms in List into some
>   float variables?

Assuming that the name of your list is `myList` and you want to store the first element of the first entry in your list:

```
List<Float[]> myList;
float x = myList.get(0)[0];
```

Comment: I'm getting a java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Float;

Comment: @Shury Are you sure that you have a `List<Float[]>`?

Comment: List<Float[]> list = this.accountRepository.functionc1c2();